# How to update demographics like Gender and Age everytime using Flurry in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

I am using Flurry(4.2.3). I have called flurry as below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
[Flurry startSession:@"API_key"];
}
```

But I want to call below method everytime when user updated his Gender and Age to send self.ageString and self.genderString to Flurry analytics.

**Note:** I am calling below method at my view controller everytime the user updated his Gender and Age.

```
-(void)flurryCall
{
    [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry startSession:@"API_key"];

    //your code
    [Flurry setAge:self.ageString];//say 18

   [Flurry setGender:self.genderString];//say m

}
```

Whenever I am calling above method. Below error is displaying from Flurry

**Flurry: startSession has been called already. It should only be called once. Returning.**

How can I send Demographics like Gender & Age everytime to Flurry.

I know that we need to call Flurry startSession at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but my requirement is to update the demographics(age,gender) everytime. As I want to store the users demographics in Flurry who are using my app.

Please Suggest any ideas where I am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no options to set demographics when session has been already started. Try to set demographics before call `startSession`.

1. Set demographics to `NSUserDefaults` when you take them.
2. Before start session just check that you have proper parameters in `NSUserDefaults` and set them to Flurry in case they exist.

Yes, you will track demographics only for sessions after session when you take this parameters.